# Cannot update FFmpeg library?

Tags: 20.04, update-manager, ffmpeg

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. When using the Software Updater I notice that it indicates that there is a security update for the FFmpeg library available. However, the selection box is not ticked. And I am not able to get this box ticked. Thus is this software not being updated. All other indicated updates are installed without problems. See a screen shot of the Software Updater below. This is now going on for quite a while and I am wondering whether somebody knows what I should do?

[image: Cannot select tick box at FFmpeg library]

I have manually uninstalled ffmpeg and then re-installed it. This did not solve the issue: the next time I run the Software Updater I get the exact same result.

EDIT 1: this is the result of running `sudo apt update`, followed by `sudo apt list --upgradable`:

`libavcodec-extra/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 all [upgradable from: 7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2]   N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.`

The output of `sudo apt list --upgradable -a` is:

`libavcodec-extra/focal-updates,focal-security 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 all [upgradable from: 7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2]   libavcodec-extra/focal 7:4.2.2-1ubuntu1 all   libavcodec-extra/now 7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 all [installed,upgradable to: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1]`

Then running `sudo apt upgrade` gives:

`The following packages have been kept back: libavcodec-extra`

I do not know why this is being kept back and not upgraded.

EDIT 2: After seeing the result listed at EDIT 1 I decide to manually remove `libavcodec-extra`. And then manually re-install it. Removing it worked, but re-installing failed. I got an error saying that `libavcodec-extra` depends on `libavcodec-extra58` but that this one would not be installed. So I manually installed `libavcodec-extra58`. This had unexpected consequences: my installation of `wine` got removed, which I use to run some Windows software. After manually installing `libavcodec-extra58` was I able to install `libavcodec-extra`. Then I had to install `wine` again, which also installed `libavcodec-extra58`.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`